# Is there a file system that supports the "Execute" permission that is supported by Windows and Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, permissions, filesystems

I'm setting up a flash drive that someone else has to use for both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04. Both contain programs for each OS. However, I cannot set the execute flag on Linux, so I cannot run any programs from the flash drive on Linux. I'll check the option only for it to uncheck itself a second later. I realized that this is due to the file system of the flash drive, which is FAT32. FAT32 does not support the execute flag. NTFS only allows the execute flag if I do usermapping or permissions, but that is out of the question, as it would take too long and be too advanced for other users that would need to create additional flash drives. Is there another file system that I can use that would help?

Comment: Linux does not respect Windows file permissions likewise Windows does respect Linux file permissions

Answer (score 2):

Files saved on FAT32 file system can be executed from Linux, Your problem is elsewhere.

When attaching FAT32 to Linux permissions are set with the mount and thus only once. Any attempts to change permissions to already connected FAT32 are silently ignored.

Because Ubuntu generally connects the flash drive automatically, it explicitly passes 'noexec' option to the mount command. This way no files from the flash drive can be executed directly.

Methods how to get around this are best explained here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/246320/how-to-mount-disc-with-exec-permissions

Comment: The `sh` and `bash` commands don't work as they're binary files. I also can't do mount or the rules file method since I will not have root access. Great answer though as it's still useful for others.

Comment: Without root access there indeed isn't much You can do. Either copy the executables to another file system (eg. to home folder), or - if `wine` is installed on the Ubuntu box - You can try running the windows version of your program (as last resort). This way you wouldn't be executing the file directly and so it should be possible to run it.